# WebSocket with extra garbled in the end of message

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to use WebSocket to post the mouse position to another device(iphone ...), After post the post the message to anyoter device , it can receieve the message from the Web ,but there is some strange thing with it ,It's have some garbled code in the end of message

first I use `prototype` to create a `Socket` and add some function with it

```
var Socket = function(){
   this.ws = new WebSocket("ws://172.16.3.103:60001");
   this.ws.onopen = function() {
      console.log("[WebSocket#onopen]\n");
   }
   this.ws.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("[WebSocket#onmessage] Message: '" + e.data + "'\n");
   }
   this.ws.onclose = function() {
      console.log("[WebSocket#onclose]\n");
      self.ws = null ;
   }
}

Socket.prototype.send = function(data){
  console.log("send data to server")
  if (this.ws) {
     var convert = JSON.stringify(data,null,4);
     var senddata = "50001#" + convert + "@"
     senddata = senddata.replace(/(\n)+|(\r\n)+/g, "");
     console.log("send:",senddata)
     this.ws.send(senddata)
     this.ws.send("50001#*")
    }
}

Socket.prototype.close = function(){
    if (this.ws) {
        this.ws = null
    }
}
var socket = new Socket()
```

then I get the position from Canvas and use websocket to send the json message(I convert the json to jsonstring in send function)

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event){ 
    var x = event.pageX-getBodyOffsetLeft(this), 
    y = event.pageY-getBodyOffsetTop(this); 
    self.onMouseMove({x:x,y:y}); 
    var dict1 = {"type":"move","x":x,"y":y}
    var newDict = {"name":"line","dict":dict1}
    socket.send(newDict)
},false);
```

After send the message `onmessage` callback will running then
I found some strange thing in console ,Most of message have garbled in the end of message

```
[WebSocket#onmessage] Message: '50001#{    "name": "line",    "dict": {        "type": "move",        "x": 313,        "y": 300    }}@�o[��n��-j��'
```

What happen?